# How to use ENUMS in Code First of Entity Framework 4.3 +?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

So.. It's already Entity Framework 4.3. I've been waiting for *real enum* support since its birth.

Are enums **finally** supported in **"code first"**?

If so, can you show me how through a code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are available as of version 5 (now in beta) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/29/ef4-3-1-and-ef5-beta-1-available-on-nuget.aspx

Walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh859576